# how to calculate age from Date of birth and how to group the records by age ranges

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column 'DOB', I need to group the records by age ranges.  but i don't know how to calculate age using DOB and use case along with it. I got that code from this site.

```
select 
  case
   when age_c <1 then 'Under 1,
   when age_c between 1 and 5 then '1-5',
   when age_c between 5 and 15 then '5-15',
   when age_c between 15 and 35 then '15-35'
```

What I want is:

```
 Under 1    1

  1-5       15 
     
  15-35     54
```

Comment: Please tag the DBMS with only one product. Those previously tagged DBMS products  might have different dialects.  .

Comment: 1. Age as of what date? (Presumably SYSDATE, but it may also be "as of January 1 of the current year", or who knows what other real-life specification; please clarify.) 2. How is a birthday of February 29 treated, in a non-leap year? Someone born on Feb. 29, 2004, has what birthday in year 2022 (non-leap year?) In some countries it's Feb. 28, 2022; in others it is March 1, 2022. In some cases (legal issues for example), the rule must be followed very strictly. Clarify with your business users if you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You presumably want some kind of aggregation query here:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN age_c < 1  THEN 'Under 1'
            WHEN age_c < 5  THEN '1 - 5'
            WHEN age_c < 15 THEN '5 - 15'
            WHEN age_c < 35 THEN '15 - 35' END AS age_range,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: If your RDBMS allows you to group by ordinals

Comment: @Andrew ...most do, and if not, then we would have to either subquery or else repeat the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH AgeData as
(
  SELECT 
  cast(DATEDIFF(DAY,DOB,GETDATE())/365.25 as int)  AS [AGE]
  FROM your_table
),
GroupAge AS
(
  SELECT [Age],
         CASE
             WHEN AGE < 1 THEN 'Under 1',
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN '1-5',
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 5 AND 15 THEN '5-15',
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 15 AND 35 THEN '15-35'
             WHEN AGE > 35 THEN 'Over 35'
         END AS [Age Groups]
  FROM AgeData
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [callGrpCount],
       [Age Groups]  FROM GroupAge 
GROUP BY [Age Groups]  order by [Age Groups]
```

Assume: DOB in yyyymmdd format